# SQL Join in same Table using condition in different table?

Tags: sql, join

How to print Student details w.r.t a Teacher ie. `StudentName` and `TeacherName` And `CourseID`?

The Table `CUSTOMERS` have all `Name` and unique `Cust_ID` for all type of users(ie students,teacher).

`COURSE` Table has `student_id` and `teacher_id` and `course_id` as columns. `COURSE` table basically gives the relation between different customers.

`student_id` and `teacher_id` are acctually `cust_ID`

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the same table twice, provided that you use aliases:

```
select c.course_id, s.name student_name, t.name teacher_name
from course c
inner join customers s on s.cust_id = c.student_id
inner join customers t on t.cust_id = c.teacher_id
```